# Video preview not showing in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, linphone

I'm doing video call implementation using Linphone. I am able to capture the camera in my phone and showing the preview of video in my app. But I need the preview of the video being captured in client camera. I'm capturing the video through texture view. This is my texture view code where I'm displaying my camera

```
 async Task PrepareSession()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
     
        try
        {
            CloseSession();
            sessionBuilder = device.CreateCaptureRequest(cameraTemplate);

            List<Surface> surfaces = new List<Surface>();
            if (texture.IsAvailable && previewSize != null)
            {
                LinearLayout fl = new LinearLayout(this.Context);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lparams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
                fl.LayoutParameters = lparams;

                displayCamera = new TextureView(this.Context);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams dparams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100);
                displayCamera.LayoutParameters = dparams;

                captureCamera = new TextureView(this.Context);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams cparams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100);
                captureCamera.LayoutParameters = cparams;

                fl.AddView(displayCamera);
                fl.AddView(captureCamera);
             
                var texture = this.texture.SurfaceTexture;
                texture.SetDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.Width, previewSize.Height);
                               
                Core.VideoDisplayEnabled = true;
                Core.VideoCaptureEnabled = true;
                Core.NativeVideoWindowId = displayCamera.Handle;
                Core.NativePreviewWindowId = captureCamera.Handle;

              
                Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
                surfaces.Add(previewSurface);
                sessionBuilder.AddTarget(previewSurface);
                
            }
```

This is the Linphone code through which they display the video preview of client camera.

```
TextureView captureCamera;
LinearLayout fl = new LinearLayout(this);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lparams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            fl.LayoutParameters = lparams;         
            captureCamera = new TextureView(this);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams cparams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(320, 240);
            captureCamera.LayoutParameters = cparams;
            fl.AddView(captureCamera);
            app.getLayoutView().Children.Add(fl);
            app.Core.NativePreviewWindowId = captureCamera.Handle;
            app.Core.VideoCaptureEnabled = true;
```

I have tried the following code combination

```
Core.NativeVideoWindowId = texture.Handle;
```

I am getting object not found exception for Core.NativeVideoWindowId. How can I add video preview directly in the layout and simply get it by it's ID. I have gone through the following link.

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-xamarin

[How to show a textureview through stacklayout in xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048398/how-to-show-a-textureview-through-stacklayout-in-xamarin-forms)

https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/tutorials

I have no clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the remote video view you must use Core.NativeVideoWindowId instead of Core.NativePreviewWindowId.
You really should take a look at our tutorials, that would help you understand how our API works better: https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/tutorials

Best regards,

Comment: I edited the question. I used Core.NativeVideoWindowId aswell but still I get object not found exception.

Comment: Then add the stacktrace of the exception and logs from the system console from the start of the app to the crash.